# Do Linear Transformations exist over vector spaces whose addition rules are not ordinary?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors, linear-transformations

Today I was studying linear transformations of vector spaces and ran across the following theorem:

> Theorem: Let $T:V \rightarrow W$ be a linear transformation from a vector space $V$ to another vector space $W$. Let $0_v$ and $0_w$ be the zero vectors of $V$ and $W$ respectively. Then,
> $$T(0_v)=0_w$$
> Proof: Consider $v \in V$. Then $$T(v)=T(v+0_v)=T(v)+T(0_v)$$
> From here we get-
> $$T(0_v)=T(v)-T(v)=0_w$$

The last step seems rather strange to me. Can we use the rules of normal addition and subtraction over vector spaces like this? Isn't the definition of the zero vector dependent on what the rules for addition and multiplication in it are? And *even* if they are different from ordinary rules, can the above theorem  be as general as the author claims it to be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By definition of vector space: $W$ forms a commutative  group with respect to "addition". Here $0_w$ is the identity of that group and $-T(v)$ is denoted as the inverse of $T(v)$ with respect to that specially defined operation "addition". Now you just put $-T(v)$ to both sides of the first equation and use group operation.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Is thus $+$ in $v+0_v$ and $T(v)+T(0_v)$ the same + or is it different?

Comment: $v+0_v$ is the "+" of $V$, the other one is of $W$. Hence are usually different.

Comment: This is a pretty standard linear algebra proof. If you look at the axioms for a a transformation to be linear it should be a little more clear. $T(v+w)=T(v)+T(w)$ and $T(cv)=cT(v)$.